# Power BI api connect to Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, httprequest, powerbi

I'm trying to connect my firebase realtime database into power bi streaming reports. as I concern, when I create a streaming datasource, power bi gives me an API, with that API I have to write a firebase function to communicate the realtime database.

how can I make that connection??

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if a direct connection is available. However, what we ended up doing was create an api call in firebase and creating a web connector in powerbi and scheduled refresh to get the latest data.